# Table empty in Azure Synapse lake database but parquet files are present in the data lake

Tags: parquet, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I've been playing around with the lake databases in Azure Synapse and have been trying to export data from my dedicated SQL pool using CETAS method to the datalake then using a lake database to map/read the parquet files that were created.

The problem comes when I try to query the table created in the lake database, it just returns no results, with an error listed 'no dataset found for myexampletable'.

I've checked and the files are in the correct location in the datalake which match the location of the table specified in the lake database. The compression used is 'snappy' when I'm exporting from the dedicated SQL pool and I've also set the compression to 'snappy' in the lake database table settings. Note that I've tried using uncompressed parquet format in both the SQL pool and the lake database, same error...

The only thing I've noticed is that the files in the datalake are created with an extension '????.parq.snappy' or '????.parq' as opposed to the usual '????.parquet' for example. Not sure if this just the dedicated SQL pool's way of naming the files?

I tried renaming them to '????.parquet' and this fixes the problem. The question is how do we get the lakehouse to read '.parq' or '.parq.snappy' files? Or is there a way to get Synapse dedicated SQL pool to export using the 'normal' file extension?

Any ideas how to fix this?

Edit: added example code I'm using (names changed of course)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [SomeExternalDataSource] WITH (
    TYPE = HADOOP
    ,LOCATION = N'abfss://somecontainer@somestorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/SomeFolder'
)

CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [CompressedParquetFormat] WITH (
    FORMAT_TYPE = PARQUET
    ,DATA_COMPRESSION = N'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec'
)

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[SomeExternalTable] WITH (
    LOCATION = 'FolderOne/FolderTwo/Etc'
    ,DATA_SOURCE = [SomeExternalDataSource]
    ,FILE_FORMAT = [CompressedParquetFormat]
) AS 

SELECT 
[Field1]
,[Field2]
,[and_so_on]

FROM 
[SomeSchema].[SomeTable]
```

Comment: hi @rocket porg, could you provide sample code .what you tried ?

Comment: Hi @SaiVamsi I've updated the post with the code I'm using. It seems like either its a shortcoming in dedicated SQL (not tried serverless yet) which should really produce '.parquet' file extensions IMHO, or maybe lake databases should support more parquet file extension types... or both probably ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else runs into this problem...

The problem ***was*** the fact that the dedicated SQL pool was exporting the parquet files using the '.parq' file extension instead of the more common/standard '.parquet' extension. The lake database was of course looking for '.parquet' files (not '.parq' files), so even though the files were there it was not finding any, hence empty tables.

In short, the lake databases and serverless pool are built to use '.parquet' file extensions, but the dedicated SQL pool writes '.parq' files. Why on Earth would anyone want file extensions to be consistent in the same 'product', lol!?! Insert face palm here...

I've reported this to Microsoft and they've confirmed you ***cannot*** change the file extension to the normal/standard '.parquet' extension, you're stuck with the file names and extension it generates. I've asked if they will update (or fix ;-) SQL dedicated pools regarding this 'issue' in the future, but I'm still awaiting reply...

As a workaround I'm still exporting from dedicated SQL pool but then I have to change the file extensions afterwards (i.e. renaming files using the API). Once that's done they get picked up by the lake database... doh!

[Here's the link to my post reporting this to Microsoft and their replies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1200090/possible-bug-or-issue-in-synapse-dedicated-sql-poo)

Answer (score 0):

The '.parq' or '.parq.snappy' extensions are not the standard extensions for Parquet files, which may be causing issues when trying to query the table in the lake database.

**Reframe SQL query as per below syntax:**

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.external_file_formats WHERE name = 'CompressedParquetFormat') 
    CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [CompressedParquetFormat] 
    WITH ( FORMAT_TYPE = PARQUET)
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.external_data_sources WHERE name = 'SomeExternalDataSource') 
    CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [SomeExternalDataSource] 
    WITH (
        LOCATION = 'abfss://pool@vamblob.dfs.core.windows.net' 
    )
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbo.dem12 (
    [registration_dttm] datetime2(7),
    [id] int,
    [first_name] nvarchar(4000),
    [last_name] nvarchar(4000),
    [email] nvarchar(4000),
    [gender] nvarchar(4000),
    [ip_address] nvarchar(4000),
    [cc] nvarchar(4000),
    [country] nvarchar(4000),
    [birthdate] nvarchar(4000),
    [salary] float,
    [title] nvarchar(4000),
    [comments] nvarchar(4000)
    )
    WITH (
    LOCATION = 'userdata3.parquet',
    DATA_SOURCE = [SomeExternalDataSource],
    FILE_FORMAT = [CompressedParquetFormat]
    )
GO

select * from dbo.dem12
```

[image]

**Or**

Another way you can resolve this issue, Using Azure synapse pipeline, copy the parquet files to another location in the data lake with the correct file extension `.parquet,` and then create a lake database and read the files from the new location.

**Reference:**

[CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&tabs=dedicated)

Comment: Hi @SaiVamsi thanks for a try but unfortunately that query doesn't export any data. Its only creating an external table and then you're selecting from it, but the file(s) must already exist in the location you specify. I'm trying to save the data to storage from the dedicated SQL pool. Also, ideally I was trying to avoid using any Synapse (or data factory) pipelines for the export, at least for data movement to try and minimise costs.

Comment: hi @rocketporg, use copy into command more for information refer this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6336/using-copy-into-command-to-load-azure-synapse-analytics-from-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2/)

Comment: Or You can directly insert data into an external table by using the INSERT INTO command. The external table is already connected to the storage account. Try these two approaches.

Comment: Hi @SaiVamsi, I can't use the COPY INTO command as I'm wanting to export to storage not import data from files in storage. Also its not possible in INSERT INTO an external table in dedicated SQL pool...

Comment: @rocketporg, there is no appropriate way to do this in a dedicated SQL pool. so better try [Apache Spark](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/read-amp-write-parquet-files-using-apache-spark-in-azure-synapse/ba-p/1456266) or Azure synapse pipeline.

Comment: To export data to an external table use CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS (CETAS).  It's very fast.  Unfortunately I was unable to get a .parquet file extension